# How to limit the amount of a string in a text file

Tags: python

I have some code that records an Input name and score and I want to make it so that there can only be 3 entries of that same name therefore I am trying to figure out how to check for a certain string in a file and make sure there is only 3 of that string. This is a code i previously found but I want to make it so once it recognises 3 names (if there are 3 names) kill the program.

```
# checks for multiple name entries max 3
def maxNamesA1():
count = 0
with open('testResultA1.txt') as myfile:
    if name in myfile.read():
        count += 1
        print(count)
```

Comment: Add the format of the input file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate through the lines to get a count, as of now you are only increasing the account for any match.

```
# checks for multiple name entries max 3
def maxNamesA1():
    count = 0
    with open('testResultA1.txt') as myfile:
        count = sum([1 for line in myfile if name in line])
    
    # to terminate 
    if count > 3: exit()
    return count
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `str.count`:

```
with open('testResultA1.txt') as myfile:
    print(myfile.read().count(name))
```